# MongoDB using an OR clause in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm using python's mongoengine to query MongoDB, and have loved it for the most part, but I'm having an issue with an [advanced query](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#advanced-queries).

Here's my model

```
class ContentItem(Document):
    account = ReferenceField(Account)
    creator = ReferenceField(User)
    public = BooleanField(default=False) 
    last_used = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

I would like to make a query for all `ContentItem`'s that are of a particular account, and are either created by the logged in user or are public.  Here's the query I wrote

```
query = ContentItem.objects.filter( (Q(account=account) & Q(public=True)) |  (Q(account=account) & Q(creator=logged_in_user)) ).order_by('-last_used')
```

or:

```
query = ContentItem.objects.filter( Q(account=account) & ( Q(public=True) |  Q(creator=logged_in_user) ) ).order_by('-last_used')
```

But these seem to be XOR where if either `public`, or the `creator` but not both. Is this expected?

Am I overlooking something? Should I do this directly with mongodb instead of mongoengine?

My current workaround is to make two different queries and combine the results,  but as the # of Content Items gets larger the result is taking a long time to come back because I need to get all items before I can order them, thereby losing all the benefit of (django) paginated results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mongoengine documentation is apparently incorrect in this case. Instead of using the bitwise operators "&" and "|", you should use the standard operators "and" and "or".

So your first query becomes:

```
query = ContentItem.objects.filter( (Q(account=account) and Q(public=True)) or  (Q(account=account) and Q(creator=logged_in_user)) ).order_by('-last_used')
```

Comment: that did the trick.   i added a note on the github account to fix the documentation https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/issues/363

Comment: This is NOT the case; see the github issue referenced above. I tried this, but using `or` instead of `|` will not apply the filter. Using `&` and `|` works just fine for me.

Comment: @Paul - perhaps you did not notice that this post was 9 months old, and that the bug has since been fixed?

Comment: @apiguy Nope. You were wrong at the first place. It's impossible to override the `and`/`or` in Python, instead you can override `|`/`&`. The source code of Q (mongoengine/queryset/visitor.py )and its history confirms that

Comment: You have to use bitwise operators. You cannot use or, and to combine queries as Q(a=a) or Q(b=b) is not the same as Q(a=a) | Q(b=b). As Q(a=a) equates to true Q(a=a) or Q(b=b) is the same as Q(a=a).

Docs ->
https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/querying.html#advanced-queries

Answer (score 13):

MongoEngine docs say otherwise. Please check this:
[image: http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html]

Comment: Mongoengine maintainer here, accepted answer is wrong, this is the correct answer

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to do the query is to use bitwise operations `|` and `&` the way you wrote it in your question:

```
query = ContentItem.objects.filter( (Q(account=account) & Q(public=True)) |  (Q(account=account) & Q(creator=logged_in_user)) ).order_by('-last_used')
```

*Note*: using the standard Python boolean operators `and` and `or` will **not** work. This is explained in the [MongoEngine documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#advanced-queries).

Answer (score 3):

you are probably import the wrong Q

```
from mongoengine.queryset.visitor import Q as mongo_Q

from django.db.models import Q as normal_Q
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/tests/queryset/transform.py

from line 134:

```
def test_raw_query_and_Q_objects(self):
    query = Foo.objects(__raw__={'$nor': [{'name': 'bar'}]})._query
    self.assertEqual(query, {'$nor': [{'name': 'bar'}]})

    q1 = {'$or': [{'a': 1}, {'b': 1}]}
    query = Foo.objects(Q(__raw__=q1) & Q(c=1))._query
    self.assertEqual(query, {'$or': [{'a': 1}, {'b': 1}], 'c': 1})
```