# Mongo engine Q class 'OR'

Tags: python, django, mongoengine, django-q

I have a list of objectIDs of users

```
friends = ['someID', 'someID']
```

I wrote a queryset to get the users associated with these objectID that I have in friends list.

```
u = UserAccount.objects.filter(Q(id = friends[0]) or Q(id = friends[1]))
```

now `u.to_json()`
outputs only one UserAccount object though both the object ID exists in database

So I checked it by separating the query, now each queryset returned a UserAccount object as expected.

```
u = UserAccount.objects.filter(Q(id = friends[0]))
v = UserAccount.objects.filter(Q(id = friends[1]))
```

What could possibly be wrong?
Is there some issue with the 'or'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match any in a list you can use the `in` [query operator](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#query-operators):

```
UserAccount.objects.filter(id__in=friends)
```

Answer (score 3):

Fix:

```
UserAccount.objects.filter(Q(id = friends[0]) | Q(id = friends[1]))
```

Comment: '&' and '|' doesn't work... see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189702/mongodb-using-an-or-clause-in-mongoengine

Comment: The answer in the SO you just posted is out of date, and I don't think it was right even at the first place. You can't override `and` `or` behavior in Python, but you can override  `|` ,`&`

Comment: result = UserAccount.objects( Q(first_name__istartswith = query[0]) and Q(last_name__istartswith = query[1])).only('first_name', 'last_name', 'user_name') 
i'm using this query too, here 'and' works fine whereas '&' doesn't work

Comment: @Praveen But is the result as same as `result = UserAccount.objects( Q(first_name__istartswith = query[0])).only('first_name', 'last_name', 'user_name')` ?

Comment: No it has some more users added up to the result

Comment: @Praveen I made a mistake, compare the result to `UserAccount.objects( Q(last_name__istartswith = query[1])).only('first_name', 'last_name', 'user_name') `

Comment: @Praveen `X and Y` equals `Y` when X and Y are both true in Python(in most other languages too)

Comment: So how do i fix this query to produce the expected result? when '&' '|' doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @Praveen Can you get the correct result if you change `id` to another field(just for test)?

Comment: @Praveen What does `What does (Q(id = friends[0]) | Q(id = friends[1])).to_query('UserAccount')` produce? It should produce something like `{'$or': [{'_id': ObjectId('5278b9b61dc689c0a2689ae3')},
  {'_id': ObjectId('5278b9b81dc689c0a2689ae4')}]}`. Does mongodb return a result if you manually execute the query in mongo shell?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40553/discussion-between-praveen-and-leonardo-z)