# Is it possible to use logical operators in mongoengine when you want to read data

Tags: python-3.x, mongoengine

I use *python mongoengine*.

I would like to know if it is possible to use conditions in objects.

ex:

```
personnes =  Person.objects(name="bob" & salary=70)
```

I know we can use *Q class* to make that or *Raw* in json mode to query database but I prefer simple multiple condition in `objects( A and B or C)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gmauch` is correct, the best way to handle logical combinations is with `Q`.

However, for your specific example, the default logic for multiple passed keyword parameters is `and`.

Therefore,

```
personnes =  Person.objects(name="bob", salary=70)
```

will only return `Person` documents that have both a `name` of "bob" and a `salary` of 70. It's the functional equivalent of `(name=="bob") and (salary==70)`

But, for anything other than a very simple sequence of `and`'d conditions, use `Q`.

And, yes, the documentation is silent about the implicit `and`.

Comment: Also, a heads up if you are using Django. Both Django and MongoEngine have a `Q`. Make sure you are using the right one. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's usually hard to affirm that something *can not* be done, but I think that this is the answer for your question. *Q* (or *raw*) seems to be the way to go if you need to use logical operators.

Getting into more details, the [official documentation for Mongoengine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#advanced-queries) says:

> if you need to combine a number of constraints using *and* and *or* this
>   is made possible in MongoEngine through the Q class.

Implying that *Q* is the way to go to use logical operators in MongoEngine queries.

Later the docs warn:

> You have to use bitwise operators. You cannot use or, and to combine
>   queries as Q(a=a) or Q(b=b) is not the same as Q(a=a) | Q(b=b). As
>   Q(a=a) equates to true Q(a=a) or Q(b=b) is the same as Q(a=a).

Finally, a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189702/mongodb-using-an-or-clause-in-mongoengine) was asked here in StackOverflow and [one of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189702/mongodb-using-an-or-clause-in-mongoengine#comment29407562_8218844) states that

> It's impossible to override the and/or in Python, instead you can
>   override |/&. The source code of Q (mongoengine/queryset/visitor.py)
>   and its history confirms that

**In short**, it seems you cannot override *or* and *and* operators and Q is the recommended way to perform logical operations.